# Skip a class hierarchy level during XML serialization

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I want to serialize a class into:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<documents>
  <document>
    <element />
    ...
  </document>
  ....
</documents>
```

I have been experimenting with the following class hierarchy:

```
public class A
{
    [XmlArrayItem("document")]
    public List<B> documents = new List<B>();
}

public class B
{
    public string id;

    [XmlArray("element")]
    public List<C> elements = new List<C>();
}

public class C
{
    public string name;
    public string value;
}
```

Unfortunately, what I get is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<A>
  <documents>
    <document>
      <element />
    </document>
  </documents>
</A>
```

So how do I get rid of "A", i.e. the type name of the outmost class?

A broader question would be, how can this be generalized? How can I skip arbitrary "levels" within my class hierarchies during serialization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outer-most class is called the "root".  You have to use [XmlRoot] to set it.

However, then you also have to use [XmlElement] on documents instead of [XmlArrayItem] in order to make it the sub-level of the root.